# Iterate in submatrices through a bigger matrix

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix

I looking for a way in which I using a for loop can iterate through a bigger matrix, in which each iteration will output a sub matrix of size (row, col, depth) (6,3,3).

My big matrix is stored as numpy matrix, and would possible also like the each iteration to be outputted as such.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(6*3,3*3,3)
>>> print a.shape
(18, 9, 3)
>>> print a
>>> b
```

The variable b should contain all the sub matrixes of size (6,3,3) from matrix a. 
Each submatrix should not overlap with the prior.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for sliding matrices? How many dimensions are in the input array? Could you add a sample case?

Comment: Yes... I guess you could call it a sliding matrix..  The dimension well.. rows are always 78 (dividable with 6). columns depends on the data length, but always dividable with 3, and depth is 3 (actually 4 RGBA, but i am slicing the alpha channel away)

Comment: So, how many such submatrices are you supposed to get from the just edited sample data?

Comment: @Divakar 3 sub matrices from the bigger matrix

Comment: Or 27? Do the math again?

Comment: How are you getting 27?

Comment: Well `a` has `1458 (18*9*9)` elems, whereas the block as `54 (6*3*3)` elems. So, by dividing?

Comment: Ohh sorry... wait. I edited the post above. 
Now... its correct.. it should be 9 sub matrices. The input shape will always have depth 3. and the sub matrixes cannot be overlapping.

Comment: I guess we are not clear on  the `sliding` terms. So, let me put a different term - Are we looking for overlapping blocks that slides along the three dimensions of the input array or distinct ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

I am assuming we are looking for `non-overlapping`/`distinct` blocks. As such we could use [`Scikit-image's view_as_blocks`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) utility -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks

BSZ = (6,3,3)
out = view_as_blocks(a,BSZ).reshape((-1,)+ (BSZ))
```

Sample run -

```
In [279]: a = np.random.rand(6*3,3*3,3)

In [280]: out = view_as_blocks(a,BSZ).reshape((-1,)+ (BSZ))

In [281]: out.shape
Out[281]: (9, 6, 3, 3)
```

---

**Approach #2**

Using just native NumPy tools like `reshaping` and `transpose`, here's one way -

```
m,n,r = a.shape
split_shp = m//BSZ[0], BSZ[0], n//BSZ[1], BSZ[1], r//BSZ[2], BSZ[2]
out = a.reshape(split_shp).transpose(0,2,4,1,3,5).reshape((-1,)+ (BSZ))
```

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/util/shape.py:94: RuntimeWarning: Cannot provide views on a non-contiguous input array without copying.
  warn(RuntimeWarning("Cannot provide views on a non-contiguous input "`

Comment: Something i should be worried about?

Comment: @J.Down Well as the warning msg states, I am guessing your input isn't a contiguous one, which depends on the source of the input. So, to be safe I guess you could go with the second app, as internally first app is doing something similar.

Comment: `    out = matrix.reshape(split_shp).transpose(0,2,4,1,3,5).reshape((-1,)+ (BSZ))
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Comment: @J.Down So, the question to you is `Are all dimensions divisible by the block size`? Like in the give sample the input array shape is (18,9,3) and thus each of those three dims are divisble by the respective sizes in  block size (6,3,3). Is that the case with your actual inputs and block sizes?

Comment: ahh. yes I had to fix something...
I like approach 1 better than approach 2, due to the readbility.. Would it be possible to make a bit more readable?

Comment: @J.Down Well I think that's the best I could do :)